ReactJS website not working after timeout in Google Chrome (Aw snap)
It is built with ReactJS. After some time (between 5-20 minutes) the site doesn't respond anymore, user can't click anywhere, can't inspect elements, it is completly down. And shortly after that there comes a white screen and Chrome displays the "Aw Snap" error message ("Oh Nein" in german).
This happens with and without browser extensions enabled, in Incognito mode, with logged in or logged out users.
It is not an issue after an event or function, as it also happens on the News page where nothing runs in the background after the news have loaded.
We use Redux as store and I suspect there is too much data saved in the storage?
Google Search only tells me to reload the page, which is no solution.
Does anyone have a clue what the issue could be? Or experienced something similar with React in Chrome?
Thanks in advance!

Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

Here are some potential causes and troubleshooting steps that might help you resolve the issue:
1. Memory Leaks:
A common cause of this issue is a memory leak in your application. Memory leaks happen when your app retains memory that it no longer needs, causing it to consume more and more RAM over time.

Use Chrome's DevTools to monitor memory usage (Performance or Memory tabs).
Look for components that might not be properly unmounted or event listeners that aren't being removed.
Check for large objects or data being stored in the Redux store that isn't necessary.

2. Excessive Data in Redux Store:
Storing too much data in the Redux store can cause performance issues, especially if the data is large and complex. This can also lead to increased memory usage over time.

Evaluate the data you're storing in Redux. Only keep data that is essential to the global state.
Consider using pagination or lazy loading for large datasets to avoid overloading the store.
Check if you're inadvertently storing entire objects when only certain fields are needed.

3. Infinite Loops or Excessive Rendering: (I faced this earlier)
An infinite loop in your rendering logic or state updates could cause your app to freeze, leading to crashes.

Check for any logic that might cause an infinite loop in your components, particularly within hooks like useEffect.
Ensure that your components are not re-rendering unnecessarily, which can be checked using React DevTools (Profiler tab).

